# Irregular characters added to beginning of file

Tags: c#

I'm following Microsoft's tutorial on creating and writing to a simple file and I'm getting unexpected results.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b93480%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Instead of writing a series of numbers to a file, I'm actually writing XML text to a file. But it's adding "Ł" to the very beginning and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
    public static void CreateFile(string xml)
    {
        var dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var fileName = "file_" + dateStamp + ".xml";
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists.");
            return;
        }

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
            {
                writer.Write(xml);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use a BinaryWriter?

Comment: That's what was in the tutorial. Changing it to a StreamWriter fixed it. Thanks! Put it in an answer down here and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you use a `BinaryWriter`. If you change it to a `StreamWriter`  this problem goes away.

Answer (score 4):

When you read the manual for [`BinaryWriter.Write(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it reads:

> Writes a length-prefixed string to this stream…

So the “inappropriate” character is in fact the lenght of the string.

You should use a [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-based writer instead (such as [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), or any other available method for outputting text files.

Also, you should **pay attention to the encoding** of the text. **Specifically, when you are trying to output an XML**, then if you had constructed it using .NET's XML manipulation means, and had it written into a `string`, then the `<?xml?>` directive will likely refer to `utf-16` encoding. This is because .NET's strings use two-byte characters. Hence when dealing with XML, it is always better to **use .NET's *native* means for serializing XML** into text output (see e.g. [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Only then the encoding will be correctly specified in the `<?xml?>` directive for sure.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using a `BinaryWriter` to write the data to the file. It will write the string in a way that it can be read later, so it will write the string length first to the file, then the string data.

Just write the file as a text file instead. You can use a `StreamWriter`, or simply use one of the static helper methods in the `File` class that opens, writes and closes the file for you:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `BinaryWriter` adds the length (as int) of the writing string before.

```
  public static void CreateFile(string xml)
    {
        var dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var fileName = "file_" + dateStamp + ".xml";
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists.");
            return;
        }

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                writer.Write(xml);
            }
        }
    }
```